# Old ExpiresByType in .htaccess causes page layout break. How to force the browser cache to reload?

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, joomla

I created a new webpage and in the old I had the following parameters in `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

 # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

  # Fonts
  ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Now, with the new webpage the design of the menu looks terrible. If I clear browser cache all looks fine. But many clients still load from the browser cache and then the pages (menu) looks terrible. What can I do? I can't wait 1 year until all browser cache reload CSS etc.

I am running Joomla 4 with SP Pagebuilder Pro and a Template called Flex.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way is to change the filenames of all your image, css, and js resources.  One easy way to accomplish this is to include a cache-busting query string on them.  For example, instead of `<img src=foo.png>` you might use `<img src=foo.png?version=1.3>`.

The web server will ignore the query string and serve the current image.  However, the query string will force browsers to fetch a new image because the URL is different.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your feedback. I am not a Developer. The images is not the problem it is only to be in the header area (menu) of all the pages. Is this controlled by CSS? And where in which files I would need to add the Version String?

Comment: You need to add it to the CSS and JavaScript files